# How to assign a soft limit to a file size in code

Tags: c, unix

I was looking over the Unix man page of write . http://linux.die.net/man/3/write

In my application i will log errors, warning and process related minor information, which are written in a log file. What i want is if the file size becomes greater than 1GB , then the process should no more be able to write into that logfile . I see the man page tells about this can be achieved and write fails .

`If a write() requests that more bytes be written than there is room for (for example, the process' file size limit or the physical end of a medium), only as many bytes as there is room for shall be written.`

Does this requires ulimit related changes ? I do not want to apply at server level but just process level for my application , so it unnecessary do not fill the disk size completely. Any suggestion what should i do here ? I believe solution will equally apply for C++.

Comment: Why not provide a logging wrapper that sums up the total bytes written? This looks like a requirement to your software and it's straight-forward to provide it yourself instead of relying on the OS to do so ... (start with `fseek()/ftell()`, then just add and compare ... this should be cross-platform)

Comment: In that case how does write takes care of it , if that is taken care by myself ? Matter fact in that case i can find size of file sing stat and see if its less than my limit i write it. But How does write takes care of it is my point

Comment: it returns the number of bytes written, so you can check whether the total size was reached. If you want a *hard* limit, make use of the `count` parameter of `write()`. Btw, if you use `ftell()` to get the file size instead of `stat()`, you'll be platform independent...

Comment: But these would be overhead write , adding number of bytes written every-time , if i am writing say 20bytes per time and limit is 20GB , this unnecessarily with add lot of time those 20bytes to reach up-to 20 GB. Thanks for ftell() thing btw

Comment: an addition is really nothing to consider performance-wise if talking about IO and syscalls. That's *magnitudes* more expensive. On the other hand, relying on the OS (and its configuration) for your application to behave as intended is something I'd consider bad architecture. But that's just an opinion :)

Comment: @Invictus: are you seriously considering "overhead" adding two integers compared to *performing a syscall*? Even just trapping in kernel is three orders of magnitude slower...

Comment: `ftell()` is a very low impact operation:  Quite a bit less than writing.  And adding numbers and doing a comparison is several orders of magnitude less than `ftell()`.

Comment: @Felix what do you sugeest using a ftell() or using GNU resource usage function as mentioned in one of the answer ?

Comment: @Invictus without knowing the exact design and purpose of your application, I'd suggest to go and write your own logging wrapper with (possibly configurable) size limit. If this is just some private *hack*, using OS limits might be a bit less work ...

Comment: Thanks , i am looking for the most reliable way to do and not any hack as i would use this in my application.

Comment: Well it all depends on your requirements. If you want to go a little "fancier", you could design a logging interface and provide an implementation for unix plattforms that uses `syslog` as its backend ... (where logrotate is typically configured)

Answer (score 2):

You can use gnu resource usage functions to set and get the per process limits.
[Gnu resource usage functions](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_22.html)
On the other hand you can do log rotation based on size. If the log size exceeds more than certain limit then create a tar file of old log and start writing new log.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Definitely the correct answer to how the question was asked.